# Why can I create a DataFrame using function returning Series?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I want to aggregate a pandas DataFrame with following function f. The original DataFrame df has many columns and I want to exract only few of them to a new DataFrame

I can not understand why I have to return a Series. I would think that I need to return a DataFrame because the output is multidimensional.

```
def f(x):
    return Series(dict(Number_of_tweets = x['content'].count(),
                       Company=x['Company'].min(),
                       Description=x['from_user_description'].min(),
                      ))

account_count = df.groupby('from_user_screen_name').apply(f)
print(len(account_count))
account_count
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete and reproducible example for your problem. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create `Series`, because for each value of column `from_user_screen_name` is returned only one aggregate value per columns. Last `groupby.apply` join all `Series` together for `DataFrame`.

Your solution is rewrite for [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) function:

```
d = {'content': 'count','Company': 'min','from_user_description': 'min'}
account_count = df.groupby('from_user_screen_name').agg(d)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! So the Series is basically one row?

Comment: @Septinel - hmmm, maybe better is says `DataFrame` should be joined from `Series` - each Series create new row of `DataFrame`

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot.